# Path to store Inno Setup output files to (Setup-*.bin)

Tags: inno-setup, bin

How to change names, extensions and locations of setup-*.bin (Inno Setup internal compression archive file)

Default archive location: `{src}`

Location where I want: `{src}\Data` (Data is a folder.)

Answer (score 5):

## **There are many way to change the output folder and base file name here are a few:**

- **In inno setup**

`[Setup]`

`OutputDir={userdocs}\Data`**(`{userdocs}`means my document,change this if you want another folder)**

- **To change Output Base File name that is `setup-*.bin` in your case**

`[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename=setup`(change `setup` to any name)

- **To change the size of `setup-*.bin`you can use**

  `[Setup]`

`DiskSpanning=true`

`DiskSliceSize=2000000000`(as your preference).

- **`{src}` is nothing but a directory constants which mean 
  "The directory in which the Setup files are located".**

PS: If you want to create script for inno setup you can use [ISTool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Setup-creators/ISTool.shtml) instead then use the script in inno setup.

**Thanks if you like my answer then accepted it.**

Answer (score 1):

*By the `setup-*.bin`, I assume you refer to output files resulting from [disk spanning](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_diskspanning). I do not know what "Inno Setup internal compression archive file" is.*

Default location for Inno Setup output files is not `{src}` (it wouldn't make sense) but subfolder *"Output" under the directory containing the script."*

You can change this using `OutputDir` directive.

Quoting [Inno Setup documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_outputdir):

> Specifies the "output" directory for the script, which is where the Setup Compiler will place the resulting SETUP.* files. By default, it creates a directory named "Output" under the directory containing the script for this.